# conda create --name doc-env python==3.10 but the version installed remains 3.18

Tags: python, 64-bit, visual-studio, python3, anaconda

I try to install python 3.7 with conda but every time I seem to get python 3.11. Then I tried to explicitly specify the channel with `conda create --name doc-env python=3.10 -c conda-forge` I noticed that I don't see the environment in the left parenthesis. How can I install my version of python in my environment? Other than Anaconda, I don't have Python on my machine. I did all that through Visual Studio Code on my Windows 11.

```
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> conda create --name doc-env python=3.10  # Créez un nouvel environnement   
WARNING: A conda environment already exists at 'C:\Users\antoi\anaconda3\envs\doc-env\envs\doc-env'
Remove existing environment (y/[n])? y

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\antoi\anaconda3\envs\doc-env\envs\doc-env

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.10


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    bzip2-1.0.8                |       he774522_0         113 KB
    pip-23.3                   |  py310haa95532_0         2.9 MB
    python-3.10.13             |       he1021f5_0        15.8 MB
    setuptools-68.0.0          |  py310haa95532_0         934 KB
    tk-8.6.12                  |       h2bbff1b_0         3.1 MB
    tzdata-2023c               |       h04d1e81_0         116 KB
    wheel-0.41.2               |  py310haa95532_0         127 KB
    xz-5.4.2                   |       h8cc25b3_0         592 KB
    zlib-1.2.13                |       h8cc25b3_0         113 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        23.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  bzip2              pkgs/main/win-64::bzip2-1.0.8-he774522_0
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2023.08.22-haa95532_0
  libffi             pkgs/main/win-64::libffi-3.4.4-hd77b12b_0
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-3.0.11-h2bbff1b_2
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-23.3-py310haa95532_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.10.13-he1021f5_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-68.0.0-py310haa95532_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.41.2-h2bbff1b_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/win-64::tk-8.6.12-h2bbff1b_0
  tzdata             pkgs/main/noarch::tzdata-2023c-h04d1e81_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.41.2-py310haa95532_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/win-64::xz-5.4.2-h8cc25b3_0
  zlib               pkgs/main/win-64::zlib-1.2.13-h8cc25b3_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages:

Preparing transaction: done                                                                                                    
Verifying transaction: done                                                                                                    
Executing transaction: done                                                                                                    
#                                                                                                                              
#
#     $ conda activate doc-env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> conda activate doc-env
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> python
Python 3.8.18 (default, Sep 11 2023, 13:39:12) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that I don't see the environment in the left parenthesis.

To do this `conda` work in PowerShell, are you using the Anaconda Powershell Prompt (i.e. the Anaconda-aware version of PowerShell)?

If you *aren't*, there should be a shortcut to it in Anaconda's Start Menu folder. Additionally, if you have more than one Start Menu folder for Anaconda, the "Anaconda Powershell Prompt" shortcut should be in the "Anaconda3 (64-bit)" folder.

If you *are* using the Anaconda PowerShell Prompt, run the following command under both your `base` environment and your `doc-env` environment:

```
$(Get-Command python).Path
```

If it returns the same value both times (especially if it returns a path not under your Anaconda install location), then I suspect your `${Env:PATH}` environment variable includes a path to a Python install with higher priority than your Anaconda installs. You'll need to edit the order of the paths in your `${Env:PATH}` environment variable.

The priority order of a given command can be reviewed via the following statement in a Command Prompt window:

```
where python
```